# Improve callback code into async await mongoose

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await, callback

I want improve my old callbacks code in mongose with async/await methods (which are much better to read and organized)

**PUT is the problem**

I a have a findById, which are correctly
The problem is when try to update document with `await user.save(userWithNewProps)`

```
// put
app.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).exec()
  if (user === null) return res.status(404).json(null)
  const userWithNewProps = {name: 'Homer', lastame: 'Simpson'}
  const userUpdated = await user.save(userWithNewProps) // Doesn't works!
  res.status(200).json(userUpdated)
 } catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).json(e)
 }
})
```

I tried to study many tutorials, and other questions, but is some difficult for me.
Can you check my error?

**callback hell**

This is the original callback code, works fine, but is the callback hell and demonic spirits:

```
// put
app.put(
    '/:id',
    (req, res) => {
        User.findById(req.params.id, (err, userFound) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err);
            }
            if (!userFound) {
                return res.status(404).json(err);
            }
            userFound.name = 'Homer';
            userFound.lastname = 'Simpson';
            userFound.save((err, userUpdated) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                res.status(200).json(userUpdated);
            });
        });
    });
```

Many thanks

Comment: what is not working ? the saving or the updating ?

Comment: check out the ',' betwen params in
const userWithNewProps = {name: 'Homer': lastame: 'Simpson'} => const userWithNewProps = {name: 'Homer', lastame: 'Simpson'}

Comment: @BinaryMan updating is the problem

Comment: @BinaryMan , sorry the comma (',') in homer simpson is only for examples

Comment: ok, try this: 
user.name = 'Homer';
user.lastname = 'Simpson';
user.markModified('name');
user.markModified('lastname');
await user.save();

Comment: @BinaryMan Thanks, works! I would like use const instead let, but is ok

Comment: *How* does it not work? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi Hello, this is the other problem. The response only send an empty obj "{}"  and 500, because the catch(e) is executed. And Node console, don't emit error

Comment: That sending errors as json yields empty objects is expected, their properties are not enumerable. Add a `console.error(e);` in your `catch`  clause.

Comment: @NubeNube very good :) so I will post my answer, please marke it as true :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from our discussion in comments, the problem is in the updating and not when saving data, so you need to inform Mongoose's change tracking of the change.

Informing Mongoose about the changes can be handled by using the markModified() [method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-markModified) and it should be before saving.

```
user.name = 'Homer'; 
user.lastname = 'Simpson'; 
user.markModified('name'); 
user.markModified('lastname'); 
await user.save();
```

Regards :)

Comment: Why would the callback-style code work without these, though?